# New Laptop not working after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

First of all I'm new to Ubuntu. First time i saw Ubuntu on my sis Laptop. I upgraded my sister's Laptop, its not working after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

Now only blank pink colour is showing and caps lock is blinking.

There's an option showing in GURB to restore to 14.04, but it'll wipe all files which i don't want(Yes i able access to GURB by pressing Shift Key).

These are the cmd which i used in terminal.

```
sudo apt update sudo apt dist-upgrade
cat /etc/lsb-release
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

While upgrading, 3-4 times a option like this came(xxx= some name was there which i forgot) in which i pressed Y.

```
Configuration file '/etc/xxx/xxxx.xxx' ==> Modified (by you or by a 
script) since installation. ==> Package distributor has shipped an 
updated version. What would you like to do about it ? Your options are: Y 
or I : install the package maintainer's version N or O : keep your 
currently-installed version D : show the differences between the versions 
Z : start a shell to examine the situation The default action is to keep 
your current version. *** Xxx.xxx (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

This option also came, it ask me to put some password.

```
Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled. UEFI Secure Boot is
not compatible with the use of third-party drivers.

(...) Ubuntu will still be able to boot on your system but these 
third party drivers will not be available for your hardware.

Disable UEFI Secure Boot? (yes | no)
```

Now I'm in big trouble because she had some important collage notes which she had collected from last 5 months.

I'm in big trouble, guys please help me.

Comment: Have you accepted these options or are yet to ?

Comment: Already accepted all these options.

Answer (score 1):

The caps lock light blinking means that there was a hard crash. Boot until you get the flashing caps lock key again, then hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, and you may see a textual screen. Take a picture of it with your phone, and add the image to your question so we can take a look.

Next lets check the file system to make sure there aren't any errors.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery Mode
- choose root access
- type `sudo fsck -f /`
- run fsck more than once if there were errors
- type `ls -alt /var/crash` and write down the filenames that you see with today's date, edit that result into your question. These are some clues as to why it crashed.
- type `reboot`
- see if you can boot to 16.04, if not, try a previous kernel
- report back

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50802/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-new-laptop-not-working-after-upgrading-from-ubu).